# Reassign ip address to a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Any idea how do i **reassign** IP address to a EC2 instance in aws?

I tried with the following.

Assign a unallocated IP during the creation of EC2. It worked but i want a way where i can reassign the IP even after the EC2 is assigned with a IP.

The "manage IP Address" option doesn't give the rewrite the existing IP address!! Any idea guys!!

Comment: You can attach Elastic IP to the running instance or interface, it will overwrite the existing auto-assigned IP.

Comment: WHY do you wish to assign a Private IP? Having hard-coded IP addresses should be avoided at all times. For example, launching an instance in a different AZ/subnet would result in a different Private IP address. You should always use a DNS name that resolves to a private IP. There is a complicated method that can allow you to assign private IPs, but you should really avoid the whole requirement in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the instance using auto-assign IP address option , AWS will randomly assign an IP for you, that you have no control.

1. You CANNOT overwrite the existing auto-assigned IP with any other IP when the instance is still running. You must shutdown the instance, allocate and an Elastic IP and attach to the instance primary network device.
2. However, if you start the instance with EIP(s), then you can allocate and de-allocate it(them) on the fly.
3. Another ways is having an extra network device assign to the instance, then you can allocate IP to the second network device.

Comment: Can i assign a private ip in EIP?I need to override existing private ip with the one i would provide.

Comment: @Nilotpal  AWS EC2 instances always use the VPC private subnet and range of IP you assign.  You need to setup a VPN gateway to the VPC in order to connect to the private IP. For those don't want to use the tedious VPN (you need a VPN client or setup dedicated VPN gateway in your network), they will resort to Auto-assign IP, and use Security policy to control the inbound traffic, e.g. only allow particular IP address connect to ssh/RDS port.

Answer (score 1):

Private IP cannot be reassigned/released. Private IP of an instance remains associated with the instance for the life of the instance even if the instance is stopped. Only when an instance is terminated, its private IP is released.